# use of prepositions from/out of/of/with to express quantity

Tags: prepositions

When talking about composition of a product, what is the best word to use?

this garment is made
from? / out of? / of? / with?
95% recycled material

Comment: Any of those would be acceptable, though _out of_ is less likely to be used on a garment label.

Comment: The most seen is: made of x% recycled material.